# How to update remaining mines label in GUI Minesweeper game?

Tags: java, structure, actionlistener, minesweeper

I am making a minesweeper game in Java, and I have the game mechanics and visuals completed. However, I am trying to find a way to update the label displaying mines remaining during the game. When the user places a flag, the count should go down by one, if they click again (effectively removing the flag, either revealing the number or mine), then the count increases by one. I have the algorithm to calculate this finished, but I can't find a way to call it within an ActionListener within the program, which needs to be done so the score label can be updated.

P.S. I'm basically creating this minesweeper game with my knowledge of a high school CS class and a little outside learning along the way, so this may, in actuality, be a terrible way to design a minesweeper program. General programming tips about design, etc., would be appreciated too.

Here's all of the code for the program, separated into four classes and one interface:

Main Method Class:

```
package minesweeper;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;


import java.awt.event.*;

public class mineBoard {

    static int bombsRemaining = 0;
    static int width = 600;
    static int height = 600;

    public static void main(String[]args){

        //  boolean gameOver = false;


            //instantiates all gui items
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JButton newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
            JPanel headingPanel = new JPanel();
            Container contentPane = new Container();
            JLabel bombsRemainLabel = new JLabel();

            //sets defaults of JFrame
            frame.setTitle("USA Minesweeper");
            frame.setSize(width,height);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true); 

            //sets defaults of container
            contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            contentPane.setVisible(true);

            //adds the components to the heading panel
            headingPanel.add(newGameButton);
            headingPanel.add(bombsRemainLabel);
            contentPane.add(headingPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

            frame.add(contentPane);

            //function that occurs when the newGameButton is pressed; creates a fresh board
            newGameButton.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
                {
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){

                            //removes previous bomb screen
                            contentPane.remove(contentPane.getComponentAt(width/2,height/2));

                            //generates new bomb screen
                            mineScreen screen = new mineScreen();

                            //calculates the total number of initial bombs
                            bombsRemaining = screen.countInitialBombs(screen.list);

                            //sets label for how many bombs remain
                            bombsRemainLabel.setText("Total Bombs: " + bombsRemaining);

                            //adds the new bomb screen to the container
                            contentPane.add(screen, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                            frame.add(contentPane);
                    }

                    //unused mouse methods
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
                });

            //while(gameOver!=true){
            //  bombsRemaining = setBombsLabel(new mineScreen(), bombsRemaining);
            //  bombsRemainLabel.setText("Bombs Remaining: " + bombsRemaining);
            //}     
    }


    //detects when a button is pressed and deducts 1 from bombsRemaining; adds 1 if the button is pressed again
    /*public static int setBombsLabel(mineScreen screen, int bombsLeft){
        for(int i=0; i<screen.list.size(); i++){
            if (screen.list.get(i).getClicked() == 1){
                bombsLeft--;
                screen.list.get(i).setClicked(8);
            }
            if (screen.list.get(i).getClicked() == 9){
                bombsLeft++;
                screen.list.get(i).setClicked(10);
            }
        }
        return bombsLeft;

    }*/


}
```

Main Panel Class:

```
package minesweeper;


import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class mineScreen extends JPanel{

        private int w = 600;
        private int h = 600;
        int diffWidth = 16;
        int diffHeight = 16;
        Random gen = new Random();
        int bombChance = 0;
        int bombs = 0;
        mineButton testForMine = new mineButton();
        ArrayList<generalButton>list = new ArrayList<generalButton>(diffWidth*diffHeight);

        public mineScreen(){

            //creates the panel that holds the bomb grid
            setLayout(new GridLayout(diffWidth,diffHeight));

            //sets the analogous array list and fills bomb grid
            genBombs(list, diffWidth, diffHeight, bombs, gen);
            bombAmountSetter(list, diffWidth, diffHeight, testForMine, bombs);

            //adds the mine and nonMine buttons to the mineScreen panel
            addButtons(list, diffWidth, diffHeight);

            //sets the original revealed locations
            setOriginals(list, diffWidth, diffHeight, testForMine);

            //allows the finished bomb panel to be seen and adds it to the JFrame mineScreen
            setVisible(true);

        }

        //detects when a button is pressed and deducts 1 from bombsRemaining; adds 1 if the button is pressed again
        /*public static int setBombsLabel(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int bombsLeft){
            for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
                if (list.get(i).getClicked() == 1){
                    bombsLeft--;
                    list.get(i).setClicked(8);
                }
                if (list.get(i).getClicked() == 9){
                    bombsLeft++;
                    list.get(i).setClicked(10);
                }
            }
            return bombsLeft;

        }*/

        public int countInitialBombs(ArrayList<generalButton>list){
            int BOMBS = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
                if(list.get(i).getID() == 2){
                    BOMBS++;
                }
            }
            return BOMBS;
        }

        public static void genBombs(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int width, int height, int bombs, Random gen){
            for (int i=0; i<width*height; i++){
                if(gen.nextInt(5) == 4){
                    list.add(new mineButton());
                }else{
                    list.add(new nonMineButton(bombs));
                }
            }
        }

        public static void bombAmountSetter(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int width, int height, mineButton mine, int bombs){
            for (int i=0; i<width*height; i++){
                if(list.get(i).getID() == 1){
                    int total = setBombsNum(list, i, mine, bombs, width, height);
                    list.set(i, new nonMineButton(total));
                }
            }
        }

        public void addButtons(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int width, int height){
            for (int i=0; i<width*height; i++){
                this.add((JButton) list.get(i));
            }

        }

        public static void setOriginals(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int width, int height, mineButton mine){
            int y = (-width)-(width/3);
            while(y<width*3){
                for (int j = ((width*height)/2)-y; j<((width*height)/2)-y+(width/3); j++){
                    if(list.get(j).getID() == 1){
                        list.get(j).iconSetter();
                    }
                }
                y+=16;
            }   
        }
        public static int setBombsNum(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int i, mineButton mineB, int bTotal, int dWidth, int dHeight){

            if(i==0){
                bTotal = bombTopLeft(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else if(i>0 && i<dWidth-1){
                bTotal = bombTopRow(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else if(i==dWidth-1){
                bTotal = bombTopRight(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else if(i==(dWidth*dHeight)-dWidth){
                bTotal = bombBottomLeft(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else if(i>(dWidth*dHeight)-dWidth && i<(dWidth*dHeight)-1){
                bTotal = bombBottomRow(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else if(i==(dWidth*dHeight)-1){
                bTotal = bombBottomRight(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else if(i==dWidth||i==dWidth*2||i==dWidth*3||i==dWidth*4
                    ||i==dWidth*5||i==dWidth*6||i==dWidth*7||i==dWidth*8
                    ||i==dWidth*9||i==dWidth*10||i==dWidth*11||i==dWidth*12
                    ||i==dWidth*13||i==dWidth*14||i==dWidth*15){
                bTotal = bombLeftCol(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else if(i==((dWidth*2)-1)||i==((dWidth*3)-1)||i==((dWidth*4)-1)
                    ||i==((dWidth*5)-1)||i==((dWidth*6)-1)||i==((dWidth*7)-1)
                    ||i==((dWidth*8)-1)||i==((dWidth*9)-1)||i==((dWidth*10)-1)
                    ||i==((dWidth*11)-1)||i==((dWidth*12)-1)||i==((dWidth*13)-1)
                    ||i==((dWidth*14)-1)||i==((dWidth*15)-1)||i==((dWidth*16)-1)){
                bTotal = bombRightCol(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else{
                bTotal = bombElsewhere(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            return bTotal;

        }


        /*public static int setBombsNum(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int i, mineButton mineB, int bTotal, int dWidth){

            if(i==0){
                bTotal = bombTopLeft(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else if(i>0 && i<15){
                bTotal = bombTopRow(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else if(i==15){
                bTotal = bombTopRight(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else if(i==240){
                bTotal = bombBottomLeft(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else if(i>240 && i<255){
                bTotal = bombBottomRow(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else if(i==255){
                bTotal = bombBottomRight(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else if(i==16||i==32||i==48||i==64||i==80||i==96||i==112||i==128||i==144||i==160||i==176||i==192||i==208||i==224||i==240){
                bTotal = bombLeftCol(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else if(i==31||i==47||i==63||i==79||i==95||i==111||i==127||i==143||i==159||i==175||i==191||i==207||i==223||i==239||i==255){
                bTotal = bombRightCol(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            else{
                bTotal = bombElsewhere(list,i,mineB,bTotal,dWidth);
            }
            return bTotal;

        }*/
        public static int bombTopLeft(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int i, mineButton mineB, int bTotal, int dWidth){
            if (list.get(i+1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i+dWidth).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i+dWidth+1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            return bTotal;
        }
        public static int bombTopRight(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int i, mineButton mineB, int bTotal, int dWidth){
            if (list.get(i-1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i+dWidth).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i+dWidth-1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            return bTotal;
        }
        public static int bombTopRow(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int i, mineButton mineB, int bTotal, int dWidth){
            if (list.get(i+1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i+dWidth).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i+dWidth+1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i+dWidth-1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            return bTotal;
        }
        public static int bombBottomRight(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int i, mineButton mineB, int bTotal, int dWidth){
            if (list.get(i-1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-dWidth).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-dWidth-1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            return bTotal;
        }
        public static int bombBottomLeft(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int i, mineButton mineB, int bTotal, int dWidth){
            if (list.get(i+1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-dWidth).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-dWidth+1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            return bTotal;
        }
        public static int bombBottomRow(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int i, mineButton mineB, int bTotal, int dWidth){
            if (list.get(i+1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-dWidth).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-dWidth+1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-dWidth-1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            return bTotal;
        }
        public static int bombLeftCol(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int i, mineButton mineB, int bTotal, int dWidth){
            if (list.get(i+1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i+dWidth).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i+dWidth+1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-dWidth).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-dWidth+1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            return bTotal;
        }
        public static int bombRightCol(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int i, mineButton mineB, int bTotal, int dWidth){
            if (list.get(i-1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i+dWidth).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i+dWidth-1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-dWidth).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-dWidth-1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            return bTotal;
        }
        public static int bombElsewhere(ArrayList<generalButton>list, int i, mineButton mineB, int bTotal, int dWidth){
            if (list.get(i+1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i+dWidth).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-dWidth).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i+dWidth+1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i+dWidth-1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-dWidth+1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            if (list.get(i-dWidth-1).getID() == 2){
                bTotal = bTotal + 1;
            }
            return bTotal;
        }


        public int getHeight(){
            return h;
        }
        public int getWidth(){
            return w;
        }
}
```

Mine Button Class:

```
package minesweeper;


import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;



public class mineButton extends JButton implements MouseListener, generalButton{

    ImageIcon bombIcon, flag;
    int clickCount = 1;
//  int clicked = 0;

    public mineButton(){
        bombIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ECLIPSE_JAVA\\minesweeper_image_files\\mineSweepBomb.png");
        flag = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ECLIPSE_JAVA\\minesweeper_image_files\\flag.jpg");
        setVisible(true);
        addMouseListener(this);


    }
    /*public void setClicked(int c){
        clicked = c;
    }
    public int getClicked(){
        return clicked;
    }*/
    public int getID(){
        return 2;
    }
    public int iconSetter(){
        return 1;
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        if (clickCount == 1){
            setIcon(flag);
        //  clicked++;
        }
        if (clickCount == 2)
            setIcon(bombIcon);
        clickCount++;
    }


    //unused mouse methods
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}


}
```

Non Mine Button Class:

```
package minesweeper;

import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;



public class nonMineButton extends JButton implements MouseListener, generalButton{

        ImageIcon flag, numZero, numOne, numTwo, numThree, numFour, numFive, numSix, numSeven, numEight;
        int numBombs = 0;
        int clickCount = 1;
    //  int clicked = 0;

        public nonMineButton(int bombTotal){
            numZero = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ECLIPSE_JAVA\\minesweeper_image_files\\numZero.jpg");
            numOne = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ECLIPSE_JAVA\\minesweeper_image_files\\mineSweepOne.png");
            numTwo = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ECLIPSE_JAVA\\minesweeper_image_files\\mineSweepTwo.png");
            numThree = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ECLIPSE_JAVA\\minesweeper_image_files\\mineSweepThree.png");
            numFour = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ECLIPSE_JAVA\\minesweeper_image_files\\mineSweepFour.png");
            numFive = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ECLIPSE_JAVA\\minesweeper_image_files\\mineSweepFive.png");
            numSix = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ECLIPSE_JAVA\\minesweeper_image_files\\mineSweepSix.png");
            numSeven = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ECLIPSE_JAVA\\minesweeper_image_files\\mineSweepSeven.png");
            numEight = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ECLIPSE_JAVA\\minesweeper_image_files\\mineSweepEight.png");
            numBombs = bombTotal;
            flag = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ECLIPSE_JAVA\\minesweeper_image_files\\flag.jpg");
            setVisible(true);
            this.addMouseListener(this);
        }
    /*  public void setClicked(int c){
            clicked = c;
        }
        public int getClicked(){
            return clicked;
        }*/
        public int getID(){
            return 1;
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            if (clickCount == 1){
                setIcon(flag);
            //  clicked++;
            }
            if (clickCount == 2){
                iconSetter();
            //  clicked++;
            }
            clickCount++;
        }

        public int iconSetter(){
            if(numBombs == 0){
                setIcon(numZero);
            }
            if(numBombs == 1){
                setIcon(numOne);
            }
            if(numBombs == 2){
                setIcon(numTwo);
            }
            if(numBombs == 3){
                setIcon(numThree);
            }
            if(numBombs == 4){
                setIcon(numFour);
            }
            if(numBombs == 5){
                setIcon(numFive);
            }
            if(numBombs == 6){
                setIcon(numSix);
            }
            if(numBombs == 7){
                setIcon(numSeven);
            }
            if(numBombs == 8){
                setIcon(numEight);
            }
            return 1;
        }

        //unused mouse methods
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
}
```

Interface:

```
package minesweeper;

interface generalButton{
    int getID();
//  int getClicked();
//  void setClicked(int c);
    int iconSetter();
}
```

Comment: The name of a class or interface  should be uppercase (MineBoard, GeneralButton).  You could use a left click to clear a button, and a right click to set / reset the bomb flag.  Take a look at my article, [Minesweeper Applet](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=300) to see some alternatives to your minesweeper code.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! How would you go about detecting a left click vs. a right click? I tried to figure it out when I was creating that part, but the mouse listener only detects left clicks (I think).

Comment: SwingUtilities.isLeftClick(event) & SwingUtilities.isRightClick(event)

Comment: Thank you! I also took a look at your article, and it was very insightful.